# Do these date strings represent the same moment of time?

Tags: string, date, datetime, iso8601

```
2023-04-24T10:28:12.1380000Z 
2023-04-24T10:28:12.1380000-05:00
2023-04-24T10:28:12.1380000+05:00
```

do these ISO strings represent the same moment of time? (although their local times are different)

I get confused sometimes, apologies if i missed any previous similar answer.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO 8601 Datetime understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906340/iso-8601-datetime-understanding)

Comment: @Joe, what i do not get clearly is whether the offset is already applied, or needs to be applied to get the local time

Comment: *(although their local times are different)* They are not. Had you intended them to be? The local time is 10:28:12.1380000 in all three example strings.

Comment: my assumption was that the string part before the Z or +- like '2023-04-24T10:28:12.1380000' always represented the datetime of UTC, then the modifier for the local after that. so, to get the local time, we have to apply the offset to that utc. It turns out my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)

> The following times all refer to the same moment: "18:30Z", "22:30+04", "1130−0700", and "15:00−03:30".

Comment: *The following times all refer to the same moment* Assuming the date is the same (nit-picking, I know).